# Associate offline profile with existing Live profile

Tags: xbox-360, achievements, xbox-network

I've had an xbox for ages racking up playtime on a variety of games. I never played online, so I left it as a plain local profile (with the intention of associating it with my LiveID as soon as I needed to).

Now, I'm primarily a PC gamer, and due to certain DRM systems (I'm looking at you GFWL) I've had to create a Live profile previously to register cd-keys.
Now this is where the issues start.

I want to associate the xbox profile with my existing Live account, so all the offline xbox data is alongside the online pc data.
Turns out to make an offline account online you have to associate it with *a brand new account*! Id est, you can already have a LiveID, but if it has an XboxLive account, you're screwed if you want to use that ID.

This would mean I would need to keep track of two accounts. One with all the PC cd-keys associated with it, the other being a portable xbox profile.

Is there any way to either;

- move achievements, et cetera, from a local account to any other account, or
- move pc game registrations to a new account

I concede it'd be impossible to have multiple XboxLive accounts associated with a single LiveID, but I have heard (who knows how true it was) you can disassociate an Xbox account from a LiveID. So if either of the above are possible I *should* be able to consolidate the various profiles under the one [original] LiveID.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge... you are correct.
So, to associate an offline Xbox Live profile with an online version is to do it from the offline profile...(Join Xbox Live)
There is an option in the Xbox Accounts dash area to remove and change your email address to another, although consider if it is already connected to another profile this may conflict.
There was once a way to copy a save and it would become yours although I'm pretty sure Live changed that after people using it for cheating and boosting.

In finishing, I suggest call Xbox support. Tell them that you want to do this, though pretty much at their end all they have to do is reimburse you the codes to put on your new account. Looks like you have to drop one though.